# check if all element are present and replace python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

I have a list something like below

```
list = ['pdf','pdf,csv','','csv','csv,pdf,txt']
```

i want to check if any elements present in list replace by 'yes' and if no element it remains empty.

The required output:

```
new_list = ['yes','yes','','yes','yes']
```

i have below

```
for l, g in enumerate(list):
if any(g) == True:
    list[l] = 'Yes'
    print(list)
```

I'm not getting required output.
please someone help me on this.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i have shown in question that is new_list @DirtyBit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since empty strings are considered `False` (and non-empty strings `True`) in a boolean context, you can use a simple list comprehension to generate your output:

```
lst = ['pdf','pdf,csv','','csv','csv,pdf,txt']
        
new_list = ['yes' if v else '' for v in lst]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['yes', 'yes', '', 'yes', 'yes']
```

Note that using `list` as a variable name is a bad idea as it will overwrite the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I agree with what Nivk said about using `list` and object name.

```
for x, l in enumerate(list):
    if len(l) > 0:
        list[x] = "yes"
list
```

output:

```
['yes', 'yes', '', 'yes', 'yes']
```

Answer (score 1):

using `lambda`

```
lit = ['pdf','pdf,csv','','csv','csv,pdf,txt']
res = list(map(lambda x: 'yes' if x else '', lit))
print(res)
# ['yes', 'yes', '', 'yes', 'yes']
```

note: don't use inbuilt functions for variable naming

Answer (score 0):

simply run this code:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
if len(list[i]) > 0:
    new_list.append("yes")
else:
    new_list.append("")
```

print(new_list)